# How to prevent removal of 3rd party kernel module?

Tags: kernel

To use a specialized interface card, I had to make and install code for an API kernel module. This was working fine when I left for the T-Day break leaving the machines running in suspended mode. When I returned, my API was broken. It turned out that I had to again remake and re-install its kernel module. Although applying Ubuntu updates didn't remove the module previously, they are the main suspect so I've disabled automatic updates.

Questions:

1. Is there some way to determine exactly what caused the kernel module to be removed?
2. How can I prevent this module from being removed unless I explicitly want to remove it?

Answer (score 0):

If you manually build kernel modules, you have to rebuild them after each kernel upgrade.

You can use `dkms` to automate this process.